# Including city and temperature data in html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm still a beginner to web development, so I apologize if this question comes off as primitive. I am simply looking to have my page display New York City with the current temperature, in the format of "[temperature]F, New York City." I want the text to have the same class stylings as my other

elements, I just want the temperature to update. The code uses bootstrap and has no javascript. Here is my html code:

```
       <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center navbar-top mt-4 mb-4">
            <ul class="navbar-left mt-3">
              <li>
                <script> document.write(new Date().toDateString()); </script>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar Brand</a>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex">
              <ul class="navbar-right mt-3">
                <li>59°F, New York City</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I recommend new users review [ask] for tips on asking questions to be enable the community to provide assistance.  You've done good work by including your code, but I'm unclear on what your actual question is-- can you update with a clear, specific question?

Comment: i see javascript in your code

Comment: At the moment, this isn't really a programming problem. It's a "Where can I get temperature data from?" problem.

Comment: my mistake, it only uses javascript to update the current date. Any other javascript would be bootstrap's, I haven't written any other lines of it

Comment: I have a basic understanding of using  APIs from openweathermap.org, what I am unsure of is how to implement the API and my API Key so that the temperature text updates with the current temperature at the specific location

Comment: This demands more than what you are asking for, this post asks the wrong question - the question here should be about openweathermap API. Once you know how fetch from the API, I'd suggest putting an ID the DOM element you want to update, and grabbing that element by id (document.getElementById("theIDofElement")) to set the inner value (element.innerHTML = \`${temperature}F, New York City\`;). PS: can't be done without javascript or server